# What is a reasonable amount to pay for 120 b&w processing?

Tags: pricing, black-and-white, medium-format, processing

My preferred local lab charges $20 to process a roll of black & white 120 film and print a contact sheet. This feels high. Is this price reasonable given the base expenses plus the time and expertise required?

(Please don't suggest that I just do it myself, I much prefer to have it done for me).

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Hi @Michael and welcome the site!  As it stands right now there's a few issues with your question that makes it a bit uneasy for our site.  Its quite localized - prices for this kind of thing will be very, very dependent on what the local market will support.  Additionally, you basically ask for a poll of users.  Check out the [faq](http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq).  Maybe you can reword it somehow, but currently its not the best fit for us.  Stick around though, we'd love to help with problems/questions we can solve!

Comment: @rfusca - respectfully wrt the "local market": I was always sending my film across the country, to Kodak processing labs, to Mystic, etc. Michael wants to get other people's data points to confirm or deny his gut.

Comment: @Pat - He said "local lab"...  And even that, the survey isn't a fit for us.  I'm not suggesting its not valid or valuable information, simply that its not appropriate for this site.

Comment: The answer is "yes it is reasonable", and yes this is off topic.

Comment: I agree the question as presently formulated is off topic.  But if it were changed to ask respondents to suggest less expensive alternatives to using local labs (and their pros and cons), that might survive (and perhaps collect some interesting answers).

Comment: Why is this off topic? We have lots of questions on pricing. (I agree that the survey is the wrong format, but "is this reasonable (and why)" seems fine.

Comment: @mattdm - For me, this is too localized, both in place and time.  He's referring to the price of his individual lab and if he wants to use local labs, then the price reasonability is really determined by that. More importantly, he's asking about a very specific price for a very specific service in a market thats rapidly changing because of the decline of film.

Comment: A discussion of how to determine if the price is appropriate or @whuber's suggestion seems better IMO.

Comment: It works out fairly cheap and easy to develop your own 120 B&W film at home after you've bought the chemicals, but that's lacking a contact sheet unless you fancy going the darkroom route

Comment: Also... it's the price of making the contact sheet that greatly increases your cost here, the processing it'self should only be a few dollars

Comment: @Dreamager It's easy to make a contact sheet with a lightbulb and piece of glass: no enlarger is needed.  You can even use a shielded candle as a safelight when developing the sheet.  I have done this in campground bathrooms and in basements (at night with foil taped over the windows).

Comment: Yes contact sheets are fairly easy if you have the dark space and worth playing around with if the darkroom aspect interests you. But the cost of chemicals and the effort to have to make space in the dark and do the whole wet processing thing will be a put off for a lot of people. Def fun though

Answer (score 5):

$20 is very reasonable.

Consider this:

**Digital** >> Shoot >> Cull >> Edit >> Prepare >> Deliver (takes A LOT of YOUR time depending on project size)

**Film** >> Shoot >> Send >> Receive >> Review >> Deliver (takes few hours, if that, you go spend that time, shooting, with family or whatever)

If you are looking for quality lab, then look no further than http://www.richardphotolab.com

You just have to incorporate the expense into your price, if you are doing this as a pro. If you are just doing this for fun, and $20 seems expensive, then reconsider using film.